# Can I exclude Android from Xamarin Forms?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin.forms

Each time I build my project Xamarin firmly reminds me that my trial has ended and that I need to get a subscription.

The Android project has been unloaded from Visual Studio, so there is something else triggering the lisence check.

What I want is stopping the nagging of the Android license.

Comment: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25471/install-visual-studio-extension-without-android-sdk?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1641743-manually-resynchronize-xamarin-licenses) they are telling:

> Log out of your Xamarin account via the IDE:
>
> 1. Xamarin Studio
>
> Top right corner of the welcome screen
>
> Xamarin Studio -> Account (Mac)
>
> Tools -> Account (Windows)
>
> 2. Visual Studio
>
> Tools -> Xamarin Account

Quit the IDE.

After that step check you account at:

> Check that the store account information looks correct. In particular
>   check for duplicate computer names on
>   https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/computers.

Than delete the remaining files: Windows

> Delete all of the following folders:
>
> ```
> %PROGRAMDATA%\Mono for Android
> %PROGRAMDATA%\MonoTouch
> %LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore\ProgramData\Mono for Android
> %LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore\ProgramData\MonoTouch
> ```
>
> In default installations of Windows:
>
> ```
> %PROGRAMDATA% will expand to C:\ProgramData
> %LOCALAPPDATA% will expand to C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local
> ```

If you have tried this and it's still asking for the license I think reinstalling VS would be the best idea. 
Otherwise visit the link (first word in answer) and try navigating on their support site for getting an answer :)